# Не могу найти ошибку в коде промиса

Tags: javascript, promise

[ссылка с кодом](https://codepen.io/mandred19/pen/LvNwqZ)

```
const callBack = () => {
    let inputRub = document.getElementById('rub'),
            inputUsd = document.getElementById('usd');

    inputRub.addEventListener('input', () => {
        const promise = (url) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('GET', url);
                request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

                request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
                    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        resolve(this.response);
                    }
                    else {
                        reject();
                    }
                });
                request.send();
            });
        };
        promise('js/current.json')
            .then((response) => {
                let data = JSON.parse(response);
        inputUsd.value = (inputRub.value / data.usd).toFixed(3);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                inputUsd.value = "Что-то пошло не так!";
            });
    });
};
callBack();
```

этот конвертер должен брать значение с current.json такого содержания

```
{
    "usd": 68
}
```

и переводить, но при запросе получается код 304 и промис переходит в reject.

Я только начал изучать промисы и не могу понять, где я допустил ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибка заключается в неверной реализации обработчика `.addEventListener('readystatechange'`

В процессе выполнения запроса статус и readyState меняется **несколько раз**. В текущем же коде:

```
if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
    resolve(this.response);
}
else {
    reject();
}
```

Promise переходит в состояние `rejected` при первом же заходе, если readyState не равен 4.

Для решения достаточно перенести проверку условия внутрь:

```
if (this.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        resolve(this.response);
    }
    else {
        reject();
    }
}
```